# Is there any way to trigger an event in iOS App for the Killed/Not Running State

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to trigger an event in iOS application when there is a signal from BLE device, for the iOS app Not Running or Killed state.

Comment: If your app is in the background and has background bluetooth mode authorised then you will get standard Bluetooth delegate calls.  If the user has terminated your app then it is no longer running and you will not get any delegate calls until the user launches your app again

Comment: Thanks for the replay.

Comment: No you are wrong. There must be a way. Tile app doing this.

Comment: @SunilKumar Did you find any solution